# Checking referer in folders outside public_html

Tags: php, security, referer

Aiming to endorse the HTTP_REFERRER, previously I used the following function, and it worked like a charm. By the way, previously all the files were stored in the `public_html` folder.

```
function refererCheck()
{
    $allowed_host = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
    $host = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST) : '';
    return substr($host, 0 - strlen($allowed_host)) === $allowed_host;
}
```

Currently, to make some of the core php files a little bit more secure, I have tried to move them to a folder above `public_html`. Moving these files to a folder outside `public_html`, makes the function to return false while checking the referrer.

With this in mind, I want to know how we can change the above function so that the `php` files inside a folder, say for example `private` folder, outside `public_html` admit the requests from files inside `public_html`. How should the logic inside the above function get changed?

To make it a little bit more clear look at the two files distributions below:

First Scenario:

```
**Public_html**
--classes/a.php
--classes/b.php
Index.php
```

Second Scenario:

```
Public_html
--index.php

Private
    --classes/a.php
    --classes/b.php
```

First scenario shows the way all my files were previously stored in the `public_html` folder. Now some of the files are stored in another folder outside 'public_html'. In fact, these files should admit just requests coming from their own folder, that is `private`, or from the `public_html`. In this case, how can we rewrite the following function to do the job.

Special thanks offered.

Comment: how are you using your private files ? with `include` ? what is the relation between the function and your private folder ?

Comment: The referrer aren't affected by the location of the files, as long as you include them from the entry point (like index.php). If your function started returning false, then there's something else that has been changed. However, relying on `HTTP_REFERER` is not recommended since that header isn't always present and can also quite easily be spoofed.

Comment: @Tuckbros. Post requests are sent to private files from the files inside 'public_html'. I want files inside private folder to admit referrers only from their own folder and from the public_html folder.

Comment: @magnusEriksson HTTP_REFERER is not my only security measure taken.

Comment: your client can't on its own access the private folder, ... you have to include the files of the private area in files of the public area to access them from a client. Can you share a example to reproduce your issue ? how do you reach the `refererCheck` function ?